# ASP Page Reload Disable Confirmation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp-classic, colorbox, reload

This may seem like a nit-picky detail, but I am wanting to disable to prompt that appears when I force a reload using the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenCBox() 
    {
        $.colorbox({ href: "NewMMR.aspx", iframe: true, width: "40%", height: "70%", transition: "elastic", onClosed: function () { parent.location.reload(true); } });
    }
</script>
```

When the jQuery ColorBox closes, it fires the parent.location.reload() event which then prompts the page to ask if you want to resubmit previously given data.

MORE DETAIL:
I am trying to call a ColorBox, perform an INSERT into the database, and then close the colorbox and reload a GridView on the parent page.  The browser is asking me to resubmit previously submitted data (which is a date range from two text boxes using a calendar extender).

I want to completely disable this prompt and I was wondering if there was some trick anyone knew of that could do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentpage was last requested with a POST, you will have avoid that if you want the prompt away, try loading with a GET instead or to reload the page with the following

```
window.location = window.location.href
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for more info about this.

Comment: This did it, caused a reload and didn't give me the prompt.  Perfect!